# force close when create sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, forceclose

here i hava an error and the application will force during start the application when i'm trying to create the sqlite in android. the application can be run when i erase the code for creating the database. so i think, maybe have a problem with my database helper class. anybody know what my mistake???ho[e someone can help.thank you..

DBAdapater.java

```
    SQLiteDatabase mDb;
DBHelper mDbHelper;

public DBAdapter(Context context){
    //this.mCtx = context;
    //mDbHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx);
    mDbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
    mDbHelper.close();
    }
```

DBHelper.java

```
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "medical", null, 1);
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  (" +
            "Staff_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "Staff_Name TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "Password TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "Staff_Acid TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "Ward_Name TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS members");
    onCreate(db);
    }
```

myactivity class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
//code for create sqlite
dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(PatientMedicalRecordActivity.this);

}
```

Comment: Please the error message with the full stack trace

Comment: You miss the table name in onCreate CREATE TABLE ?

Comment: Yes, probably you meant to write `"CREATE TABLE members ("` ...

Comment: ya ya..i missed it..thank you...this is my problem. just solved it.forget to put table name.already spend almost 4 hours to find the solution.